# Is OAS 2.0 or 3.0 is supported in Mule 3.9? If yes then how we can use?

Tags: mule, openapi

Is OAS 2.0 or 3.0 specification is supported in **Mule runtime 3.9**? If yes, please let me know the configuration and requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Only Mule 4.x and Studio 7.x support OAS 2.0 and OAS 3.0. Technically speaking it is the APIKit module for Mule 4 that support OAS rather than the Mule runtime. That version of APIKit is not compatible with Mule 3.x.